# how to solve cors error in react and fast api

Tags: reactjs, cors, fastapi

I added allow_origins in fast api, but the error remains the saem , please help,

here is my react code where I try to connect and emit the message:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io(
  'https://samsara-chat.herokuapp.com/chatroom/check-chat?token=8acfbead5bb2070f112975dc188400b4bac8127b&receiver=saken2.0'
)

function Socket() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState()
  console.log(message, 'message')
  const sendMessage = () => {
    socket.emit('message:', { message: message })
  }
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={sendMessage}>send message</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default Socket
```

Here is my fast api code where I gave allow origins

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from server.routers import chatrooms
from server.routers.socketio import sio

socket_app = socketio.ASGIApp(sio)

# TODO CORS
app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    # allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_origins=["http://localhost","http://127.0.0.1:3000", 'http://localhost:8080', "http://localhost:3000", "https://samsara-web.netlify.app"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
app.include_router(chatrooms.router, prefix='/chatroom')

app.mount("/", socket_app)
```

`The problem is Access to fetch at 'https://samsara-chat.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?token=6ba855c88f67c3fbf9a864ef617e41a696745fbb&receiver=saken2.0&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O4uyi_R' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000', but only one is allowed. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```py
origins = [
    "*"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

Comment: I'm a very beginner with FastAPI and web server things. I had a simiar problem with this. Anyway it worked. I can be sure that the probelm from CORS issue. Thank you for your tips.